# Two buttons in a form, Both called

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

Here's my ASP.NET form.  When I click one button it calls both jQuery functions.  It's probably a rudimentary HTML question but I'm not sure why:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="testDialog">
    </div>

    <p><input type="button" id="invoke1" value="test 1" /></p>

    <input type="button" id="invoke2" value="test 2" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input:invoke1").click(function(){
            showSomething("testDialog");
        });

        $("input:invoke2").click(function(){
            showSomething2("test.aspx", options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you notice the other answers which are more concise and correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ID is unique for the document I see no need to include input with it, as follows

```
$("#invoke1").click()
$("#invoke2").click()
```

Answer (score 3):

shouldnt those selectors be

```
$("input#invoke1") and  $("input#invoke2")
```

Comment: if that's the case then why did : work in terms of getting an event to fire and both functions to run?  Probably you're right, the .click was happening for anything clicked because it was not properly referencing the buttons so when I clicked anything, both click events ran.

Comment: so then I guess when would you use :, I thought I saw this in one of my jQuery books..input:  I forget where I got this idea from.

Answer (score 0):

try just

```
 $("#invoke1").click(function(){
        showSomething("testDialog");
    });

    $("#invoke2").click(function(){
        showSomething2("test.aspx", options);
    });
```

since id's should be unique, this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could even try

```
$("#invoke1")... and  $("#invoke2")...
```